# Why does opencv2/core/eigen.hpp not include Eigen/Core

Tags: c++, opencv, include, eigen

Whenever I want to use functions like `cv::eigen2cv()`,

```
#include <opencv2/core/eigen.hpp>
```

is not enough and I have to include Eigen as well

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <opencv2/core/eigen.hpp>
```

Is there any design/compilation reason why [opencv2/core/eigen.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a34fbf7/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp) does not include Eigen itself?

Please note that this indeed reads like a bug-report (which SO is not the place for) but is actually meant as question about includes and template libraries like Eigen.